# Need help with player skull dropping commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to make a command block system for the latest 1.12 snapshot that makes players drop their heads when killed for my survival world, but I can't seem to find a tutorial that works. I've watched 3 different tutorials, and read one on PMC, but no matter what I do, none of them work. So I was wondering if anybody here knew of a system that worked for them in 1.12 snapshots.

Comment: Is there a limited list of player names you need it to work for? Otherwise this isn't possible.

Comment: I only need it to work for 2 (possibly 3) seperate players.

Comment: Do you know the names of these players beforehand (e.g: its you and two friend's accounts?)

Comment: yes, it is just me and my 2 friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add an objective to track when a player dies:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount
```

Then, on a clock in the following order:

```
execute @a[score_Deaths_min=1,name=<PLAYER1>] ~ ~ ~ summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"<PLAYER1>"}}}
execute @a[score_Deaths_min=1,name=<PLAYER2>] ~ ~ ~ summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"<PLAYER2>"}}}
execute @a[score_Deaths_min=1,name=<PLAYER3>] ~ ~ ~ summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"<PLAYER3>"}}}
scoreboard players set @a[score_Deaths_min=1] Deaths 0
```

Replace `<PLAYER1>`, `<PLAYER2>`, and `<PLAYER3>` with the names of the players you want this to work for (you can duplicate that command if you want to add more players).

This will make anyone with a Deaths score of 1 summon their own head, and then it sets their Deaths score back to 0 so they don't repeatedly summon their own head.